# Finding the (1,1) component of $e^{-\mathbb{A}^2}$ for $\mathbb{A}$ a superconnection

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, lie-superalgebras

Let $E=E^+\oplus E^-$be a holomorphic superbundle over a compact Kahler manifold, and $v:E^+\oplus E^-$ an odd bundle map. Assume that both $E^+$ and $E^-$ are endowed with Hermitian metrics, and denote by $\nabla^{\pm}$ the respective Chern connections. We denote by $\nabla=\nabla^+\oplus \nabla^-$ the induced connection on $E$. Let us define a superconnection (in the sense of Quillen)
$$\mathbb{A}=\nabla+ V$$
for $V=v+v^*$. The curvature of $\mathbb{A}$ is then
$$\mathbb{A}^2=\nabla^2+ [\nabla ,V]+V^2.$$
I am trying to compute the (1,1) component (i.e. the endomorphism valued differential form of degree (1,1)) of the form
$$e^{-\mathbb{A}^2}.$$
Since the terms of the curvatures do not commute it seems to require some form of the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula. But I could not make sense of it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A formula that comes to mind is the Duhamel formula, which involves integrals over simplices parametrised by $0=t_0\le\cdots\le t_n=1$ of terms of the form $e^{(t_0-t_1)\mathbb{A}^2}(\mathbb{A}^2-\nabla^2)e^{(t_1-t_2)\mathbb{A}^2}\cdots e^{(t_[n-1}-t_n)\mathbb{A}^2}$. The integrands themselves involve convolutions over your manifold.